# AntDesign TimePicker in as Input Component in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

im trying to integrate ant design TimePicker (https://ant.design/components/time-picker/#API) with Material UI which the rest of our platform is built with.
I'm following this guide (https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#integration-with-3rd-party-input-libraries) in integrating with 3rd party libs. But I get this error

> Uncaught Error: Material-UI: Expected valid input target. Did you use
> a custom `inputComponent` and forget to forward refs?

I think the error is that the ant-design TimePicker does not satisfy the required interface of an input component. Another problem is that ...

> "The provided input component should handle the inputRef property. The
> property should be called with a value that implements the following
> interface:"

```
interface InputElement {
  focus(): void;
  value?: string;
}
```

But I'm not sure how to do that, so would appreciate some help integrating the two libraries.

```
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react'
import { Moment } from 'moment'
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'
import { FormControl, InputLabel, FormHelperText, OutlinedInput } from '@material-ui/core'
import * as S from './styled'

export interface Props {
  id: string
  defaultValue: Moment
  displayFormat: string
  disabledHours: () => number[]
  onChange?: (value) => void
}

interface CustomProps extends Props {
  // inputRef: (ref: HTMLInputElement | null) => void
  inputRef: (ref: any | null) => void
}

function TimePickerCustom(props: CustomProps): ReactElement {
  const { inputRef, defaultValue, displayFormat, disabledHours, onChange, ...other } = props

  return (
    <S.TimePicker
      {...other}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      format={displayFormat}
      disabledHours={disabledHours}
      showNow={false}
      bordered={false}
      onChange={onChange}
      hideDisabledOptions
      ref={(ref: any) => {
        inputRef(ref ? ref.inputElement : null)
      }}
    />
  )
}

export default function HourMinPicker({ id }: Props): ReactElement {
  return (
    <FormControl variant="outlined">
      <InputLabel variant="outlined" htmlFor={id}>
        Duration
      </InputLabel>
      <OutlinedInput
        id={id}
        aria-describedby={`${id}-helper-text`}
        inputComponent={TimePickerCustom as any}
      />
      <FormHelperText id={`${id}-helper-text`}>Use format HH:mm, ex 12:45</FormHelperText>
    </FormControl>
  )
}
```